# Can not create user on clean debian setup

Tags: ruby, gitlab, sidekiq, gitlab-omnibus

Currently I want test the gitlab CE version via Omnibus on a clean debian 8 setup (only SSH- and NFS installed).

Installation and setup worked without problems. Now I wanted to create a new user and this doesn't work.

After click at "Create user" at the bottom of the form, I receive a 500er page. Name, username and email are unique.

The sidekiq log say that the user can not be found:

- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15497 2016-01-08T14:08:50.152Z 567 TID-tybs8 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-c01fd16dc6ecb6f68724dab4 INFO: start
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15656 2016-01-08T14:08:50.156Z 567 TID-tybs8 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-c01fd16dc6ecb6f68724dab4 INFO: fail: 0.004 sec
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15666 2016-01-08T14:08:50.156Z 567 TID-tybs8 WARN: {"class"=>"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper", "wrapped"=>"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob", "queue"=>"mailers", "args"=>[{"job_class"=>"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob", "job_id"=>"4232d503-c72a-449e-a8d0-64f3d1405c39", "queue_name"=>"mailers", "arguments"=>["Notify", "new_user_email", "deliver_now", 3, "CNDxYws5Ye_hUaw765dJ"], "locale"=>"en"}], "retry"=>true, "jid"=>"c01fd16dc6ecb6f68724dab4", "created_at"=>1452261957.4844916, "enqueued_at"=>1452262130.1520908, "error_message"=>"Couldn't find User with 'id'=3", "error_class"=>"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound", "failed_at"=>1452261957.4914882, "retry_count"=>3, "retried_at"=>1452262130.1563768}
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15670 2016-01-08T14:08:50.156Z 567 TID-tybs8 WARN: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=3
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15674 2016-01-08T14:08:50.156Z 567 TID-tybs8 WARN: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:324:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15674 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:444:in `find_one'
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15674 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:423:in `find_with_ids'
- 2016-01-08_14:08:50.15675 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
- ...

In the application.log: January 08, 2016 15:05: User "XXX" (xxx) was created

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in GitLab based on this:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq

You might want to report this to the GitLab folks or upgrade to the latest version.